# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 in Laravel and MariaDB error in migrations

Tags: laravel, mariadb

Environment:

Laravel 5.5.44

MariaDB 10.4.7

I am trying to execute the migrations, and it gives me the following error but only in one table.
The migration code is as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class CreateVehicleTable extends Migration
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('risk_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('b7code')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('b7type')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('b7class', 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('b7pgclass', 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('brand', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('model', 100)->nullable();
            $table->string('version', 250)->nullable();
            $table->string('plate', false)->nullable();
            $table->integer('price')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('frame', 100)->nullable();
            $table->integer('power')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->integer('engine_capacity')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->integer('vehicle_category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->date('registration_date')->nullable();
            $table->char('usage', 1)->default('P')->nullable();
            $table->integer('circulation_region_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('accessories', false)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('vehicles');
    }
}
```

The result of the execution is as follows

In Connection.php line 664:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to us  
  e near ') default character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci' at line 1 (SQL: create table `vehicles` () default character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci)
```

In Connection.php line 452:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to us  
  e near ') default character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci' at line 1
```

Comment: For the sake of testing, what happens if you remove all the defaults from your migrations?
You can actually remove all the defaults because those columns already use the nullable, which will automatically add the null record

Comment: Looks like it doesn't pick up the columns. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: For MariaDB you should use the mysql driver. Can you also share how you set this up?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the migration in Laravel and it worked fine. You might want to catch the full query and see what that tells you.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CreateVehicleTable extends Migration
{

     use SoftDeletes;

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('risk_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('b7code')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('b7type')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('b7class', 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('b7pgclass', 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('brand', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('model', 100)->nullable();
            $table->string('version', 250)->nullable();
            $table->string('plate', false)->nullable();
            $table->integer('price')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('frame', 100)->nullable();
            $table->integer('power')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->integer('engine_capacity')->unsigned()->nullable()>default(null);
            $table->integer('vehicle_category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->date('registration_date')->nullable();
            $table->char('usage', 1)->default('P')->nullable();
            $table->integer('circulation_region_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('accessories', false)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            DB::listen(function($query) {           
                var_dump( $query->sql . ' [' . implode(', ', $query->bindings) . 
            ']');

            }); 

         });
    }
```

You should get this (in your case with different collation) :

```
create table `vehicles` 
(`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`risk_id` int unsigned null,
`b7code` int unsigned null,
`b7type` int unsigned null,
`b7class` varchar(2) null,
`b7pgclass` varchar(2) null,
`brand` varchar(50) null,
`model` varchar(100) null,
`version` varchar(250) null,
`plate` varchar(191) null,
`price` int unsigned null,
`frame` varchar(100) null,
`power` int unsigned null,
`engine_capacity` int unsigned null,
`vehicle_category_id` int unsigned null, 
`registration_date` date null, 
`usage` char(1) null default 'P',
`circulation_region_id` int unsigned null,
`accessories` varchar(191) null,
`created_at` timestamp null,
`updated_at` timestamp null,
`deleted_at` timestamp null)
default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Run this directly in mysql or phpMyAdmin that might make it easier for you to debug it.